# How to determine the Office version programmatically using the Inno Setup?

Tags: ms-office, inno-setup

I have two types of Office add-ins – one for Office 2013 and another for other versions (2003-2010).
I use Inno Setup for distribution package.
Is it possible to determine the Office version that installed on target machine and than to run the right installation file?

I tried to write the code that detects the Word version and installs appropriate files but I failed to compile it. Since this is the first time that I write such a code, I would like to ask you to take a look on my code.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg2013.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: "Install2013"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0;
Source: "C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg2010.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: "Install2010"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; 
Source: "C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg2013x86.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: "Install2013"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: regserver noregerror ignoreversion 32bit 
Source: "C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg2013x64.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: "Install2013 and Is64BitInstallMode"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: regserver noregerror ignoreversion 64bit 
Source: "C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg2010x84.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: "Install2010"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: regserver noregerror ignoreversion 32bit
Source: "C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg2010x64.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: "Install2010 and Is64BitInstallMode"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: regserver noregerror ignoreversion 64bit 

Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Program\AppforWord"; ValueName: "AppBarStyle"; ValueType: String; ValueData: "1"; Components: "AppforWord"; Check: "Install2010"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: uninsdeletevalue 
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Program\AppforExcel"; ValueName: "Enable"; ValueType: String; ValueData: "2"; Components: "AppforWord"; Check: "Install2010"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Program\AppforWord"; ValueName: "AppBarStyle"; ValueType: String; ValueData: "1"; Components: "AppforWord"; Check: "Install2013"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: uninsdeletevalue 
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Program\AppforExcel"; ValueName: "Enable"; ValueType: String; ValueData: "2"; Components: "AppforWord"; Check: "Install2013"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: uninsdeletevalue

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyProg 2013"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg2013.exe"; Comment: "The settings for My Program 2013"; Check: "Install2013"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0;
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyProg 2010"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg2010.exe"; Comment: "The settings of My Program"; Check: "Install2010"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0;
```

```pascal
[Code]
{ Get office version }
function IsInstall2013(): boolean;
var
    success: boolean;
    OfficeVer: cardinal;
begin
    success :=
        RegQueryDWordValue(
            HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, 'Word.Application\CurVer', Word.Application.15' );
    Result := success and (OfficeVer = Word.Application.15);
end;

{ RETURNS OPPOSITE OF IsInstall2013 FUNCTION }
function Install2013(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (IsInstall2013 = false);
end;

{ RETURNS OPPOSITE OF not Office2013 FUNCTION }
function Install2010(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (IsInstall2010 = true);
end;
```

Since I also would like to create an Inno Setup installation routine which detects the version of Office someone is using. I have tried various iterations of the above code and can't seem to get things to work.

My objective is simple... install files A,B,C if someone is using Office 2010. If someone is using Office 2013, install files D,E,F,.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0` `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\ProductVersion`

Comment: Hey Roben, sorry for not having replied earlier, I had not seen your comment =X
Well, as I said above, "I also would like to create an installation routine Inno Which detects the version of Office someone is using." But I tried all ways and I cannot make it work. Could you help me with this, please?

Comment: Well maybe `RegGetSubkeyNames` or `if RegKeyExists` could help here?

Comment: And what error are you getting when compiling? At a first glance, your logic is all wrong in the `InstallXXXX` functions, with one of them geting the value of an undefined variable.

Comment: @Deanna, OP has obviously unenclosed string value passed to the expected DWORD declared parameter (what doesn't make compiler happy). Also the following comparison is wrong. It's not possible to compare DWORD value with string. HJSC, you may fix your code with [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/CHhQHirx).

Comment: @TLama I didn't go into detail without knowing what I was looking for. I only noticed the function logic which doesn't seem to tie up.

Comment: I love u guys!! TLama, It worked perfectly in office 2013, but the setup didn't identify previous versions of office (2003-2010) to install the appropriate files. It would be [someting like this](http://pastebin.com/0y44C9Lm).

Comment: Also, make sure you handle multipel versions being installed.

Comment: Deanna, this is exactly the point. Could you help me demonstrating some examples? I'm not having success in searches. my heartfelt thanks to all of you ^^

Comment: I use code I found [here](http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/0/waArticleBookmark.6486149)